# Computing remainders modulo $\prod_{i\in S} (x-x_i)$ fast using FFT

Tags: polynomials

*Note: Originally asked on Math StackExchange [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2731767/computing-remainders-modulo-prod-i-in-s-x-x-i-fast-using-fft), without an answer. Figured I should try here, since this is a more research-level question.*

I am trying to implement a fast polynomial *multipoint evaluation* algorithm via FFT (e.g., the one described in Chapter 10.1 of "Modern Computer Algebra," 3rd edition).
I should mention that the polyonomial being evaluated is the formal derivative $N'(x)$ of: $$N(x) = (x-x_1)(x-x_2)\cdots(x-x_k)$$

Specifically, we're evaluating $N'(x)$ at *distinct* points $x_1, x_2, \dots, x_k$, where $k$ is a power of two.

I'm looking for *any mathematical tricks* that will lead to *practical* improvements in the multipoint evaluation algorithm.
AFAICT, the main bottleneck will be computing remainders after division by $(x - x_i)\cdots(x-x_j)$.

As a refresher, at any "node" in the multipoint evaluation tree, we have a subset of points $x_i, \dots, x_j, x_{j+1}, \dots, x_\ell$, a previous remainder $R(\cdot)$, and we want to compute:
\begin{align*}
R(x) &\bmod (x - x_i)\cdots(x-x_j)\\
R(x) &\bmod (x - x_{j+1})\cdots(x-x_\ell)
\end{align*}

Initially, $R(x) = N'(x)$.
Furthermore, the dividend $R$ has degree $\le 2n-1$ while the divisor has degree $n$.
Initially $n = k/2$, so it's a power of two, and then $n$ gets halved as we go down the multipoint evaluation tree.

I am aware there is a $O(n\log{n})$ algorithm based on FFT for computing remainders.
For example, the "reversal-based" algorithm described in Chapter 9.1 of "Modern Computer Algebra," 3rd edition first computes the quotient by computing a modular inverse and then computes the remainder.
(There is also a "reciprocal-based" algorithm described in Chapter 8.3 of "The Design and Analysis of Computer Algorithms," but I suspect this is slower.)

**Is there any way to speed up this reversal-based division algorithm** given our particular setting:

- We do not need the quotient, only the remainder.
- We only need to divide by $(x - x_i)\cdots(x-x_j)$, for some $i,j$ where $1 \le i,j \le k$.
- $x_i$ can be an $\ell$th root of unity ($\ell > k$) but **not necessarily** the $i$th one (or $i-c$th one)
- $k$ is a power of two or can be adjusted as needed
- We're doing a multipoint evaluation on $N'(x)$

The only mathematical trick I could find was in Todd Mateer's *"Fast Fourier Transform Algorithms with Applications"* PhD thesis ([pdf](https://tigerprints.clemson.edu/all_dissertations/231/)), in Sec 7.5, pg 194.

Comment: If $x_i$ are the $k$-th power roots of unity, then $N(x)=x^k-1$ and $N'(x)=kx^{k-1}$ can be trivially evaluated at any point.

Comment: Thank you! I messed up but updated the post: The $x_i$'s can be an $\ell$th root of unity for some $\ell > k$ but they won't always be the $i$th $\ell$th root of unity. In other words, it's possible to have $x_1 = \omega^2, x_2 = \omega^5, x_3 = \omega^7, \dots$.

Comment: If $g(x)=\prod (x-x_i)$ with $x_i$ all distinct, and $f$ is any polynomial, then the remainder of $f$ upon division by $g$ is (by Lagrange Interpolation) $$ \sum f(x_i) \frac{(\partial _i g)(x_i)}{g'(x_i)}.$$ I don't know if that is convenient to you.

Comment: Thank you! Can you please clarify the $(\partial _i g)(x_i)$ notation? I'm assuming $g'(x_i)$ is the formal derivative of $g$ evaluated at $x_i$, but what is $(\partial _i g)(x_i)$? Is $\partial_i$ the $i$th Lagrange coefficient? Are you composing it with $g$?

Comment: Thje product $g(x)=\prod (x-x_i)$ may be viewed as a function of $x,x_1,\cdots,x_n$ in $(n+1)$ variables. $(\partial _i g)(x)$ is the derivative with respect to the variable $x_i$ .

Comment: In the first formula above I should have written $(\partial _i g)(x)$ and not $(\partial _i g)(x_i)$

Comment: Oh, I see. It's basically the Lagrange formula applied to $f(x) \bmod \prod (x-x_i)$. Never saw it stated in this way before. Thank you! Unfortunately, not sure how I can make use of it. The reason I'm asking about computing remainders fast is precisely because I want to speed up Lagrange interpolation itself. Computing your formula naively would take $O(n^2)$ time when $\deg{g} = n$. Computing it asymptotically faster reduces to computing remainders fast!

Comment: Ah, too bad! I thought computing $\prod _{j\neq i}(x-x_j)$ and $, f(x_i), g'(x_i)$ may be easier.

Comment: Computing $\prod _{j\neq i}(x-x_j),\forall i$ can be done in $O(n)$ time (for a fixed $x$). Computing $g'(x_i),\forall i$ takes $O(n^2)$ time, unfortunately. Even if that could be done faster (which is what I'm trying to do via FFT multipoint evaluation), computing $f(x_i),\forall i$ would still take $O(n^2)$ time (or can be sped up using FFT multipoint evaluation, which reduces to computing remainders fast).